# File API upload file

Tags: php, javascript, file, html

I am aware that the File API only exposes the name, contents, size and modified date of a file.

I was wondering if it was possible to do the equivalent of reading a file straight into a byte[] and streaming it to a php server where the file can be recreated/saved keeping things like **Creation Date** intact or at least readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the File API indeed does not support determining the creation date. There is no way to get that.

In general, [many filesystems don't even store it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata), so even the API would include the creation date, it would be undefined in many cases.

Some file formats contain a section of metadata which you can parse on the server. For example, if your uploads are images, have a look at php's [exif](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php) and/or [`iptcparse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iptcparse.php) functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not if you use javascript only. Using flash it should be trivial, but since 'Create date' and similar attributes are not part of the file, but the file system it resides on, js can't see them.